# gcc-10.0.1 Specific Segfault

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have an [R package](https://github.com/brodieG/vetr/tree/v0.2.8) with C compiled code that's been relatively stable for quite a while and is frequently tested against a broad variety of platforms and compilers (windows/osx/debian/fedora gcc/clang).

More recently a new platform was added to test the package again:

```
Logs from checks with gcc trunk aka 10.0.1 compiled from source
on Fedora 30. (For some archived packages, 10.0.0.)

x86_64 Fedora 30 Linux

FFLAGS="-g -O2 -mtune=native -Wall -fallow-argument-mismatch"
CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection"
CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-parentheses -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection"
```

At which point the compiled code promptly started segfaulting along these lines:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x1d00000001, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

I've been able to reproduce the segfault consistently by using the [`rocker/r-base`](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base) docker container with `gcc-10.0.1` with optimization level `-O2`.  Running a lower optimization gets rid of the problem.  Running any other set-up, including under valgrind (both -O0 and -O2), UBSAN (gcc/clang), shows no problems at all.  I'm also reasonably sure this ran under `gcc-10.0.0`, but don't have the data.

I ran the `gcc-10.0.1 -O2` version with `gdb` and noticed something that seems odd to me:

[image: gdb vs code]

While stepping through the highlighted section it appears the initialization of the second elements of the arrays is skipped (`R_alloc` is a wrapper around `malloc` that self garbage collects when returning control to R; the segfault happens before return to R).  Later, the program crashes when the un-initialized element (in the gcc.10.0.1 -O2 version) is accessed.

I fixed this by explicitly initializing the element in question everywhere in the code that eventually led to the usage of the element, but it really should have been initialized to an empty string, or at least that's what I would have assumed.

Am I missing something obvious or doing something stupid?  Both are reasonably likely as C is my second language by *far*.  It's just strange that this just cropped up now, and I can't figure out what the compiler is trying to do.

---

**UPDATE**: Instructions to reproduce this, although this will only reproduce so long as `debian:testing` docker container has `gcc-10` at `gcc-10.0.1`.  Also, **don't just run these commands if you don't trust me**.

Sorry this is not a minimal reproducible example.

```
docker pull rocker/r-base
docker run --rm -ti --security-opt seccomp=unconfined \
  rocker/r-base /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install gcc-10 gdb
gcc-10 --version  # confirm 10.0.1
# gcc-10 (Debian 10-20200222-1) 10.0.1 20200222 (experimental) 
# [master revision 01af7e0a0c2:487fe13f218:e99b18cf7101f205bfdd9f0f29ed51caaec52779]

mkdir ~/.R
touch ~/.R/Makevars
echo "CC = gcc-10
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection
" >> ~/.R/Makevars

R -d gdb --vanilla
```

Then in the R console, after typing `run` to get `gdb` to run the program:

```
f.dl <- tempfile()
f.uz <- tempfile()

github.url <- 'https://github.com/brodieG/vetr/archive/v0.2.8.zip'

download.file(github.url, f.dl)
unzip(f.dl, exdir=f.uz)
install.packages(
  file.path(f.uz, 'vetr-0.2.8'), repos=NULL,
  INSTALL_opts="--install-tests", type='source'
)
# minimal set of commands to segfault
library(vetr)
alike(pairlist(a=1, b="character"), pairlist(a=1, b=letters))
alike(pairlist(1, "character"), pairlist(1, letters))
alike(NULL, 1:3)                  # not a wild card at top level
alike(list(NULL), list(1:3))      # but yes when nested
alike(list(NULL, NULL), list(list(list(1, 2, 3)), 1:25))
alike(list(NULL), list(1, 2))
alike(list(), list(1, 2))
alike(matrix(integer(), ncol=7), matrix(1:21, nrow=3))
alike(matrix(character(), nrow=3), matrix(1:21, nrow=3))
alike(
  matrix(integer(), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("R", "G", "B"))),
  matrix(1:21, ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("R", "G", "B")))
)

# Adding tests from docs

mx.tpl <- matrix(
  integer(), ncol=3, dimnames=list(row.id=NULL, c("R", "G", "B"))
)
mx.cur <- matrix(
  sample(0:255, 12), ncol=3, dimnames=list(row.id=1:4, rgb=c("R", "G", "B"))
)
mx.cur2 <-
  matrix(sample(0:255, 12), ncol=3, dimnames=list(1:4, c("R", "G", "B")))

alike(mx.tpl, mx.cur2)
```

Inspecting in gdb pretty quickly shows (if I understand correctly) that
`CSR_strmlen_x` is trying to access the string that was not initialized.

**UPDATE 2**: this is a highly recursive function, and on top of that the string initialization bit gets called many, many times.  This is mostly b/c I was being lazy, we only need the strings initialized for the one time we actually encounter something we want to report in the recursion, but it was easier to initialize every time it is possible to encounter something.  I mention this because what you'll see next shows multiple initializations, but only one of them (presumably the one with address <0x1400000001>) is being used.

I can't guarantee that the stuff I'm showing here is directly related to the element that caused the segfault (though it is the same illegal address acccess), but as @nate-eldredge asked it does show that the array element is not initialized either just before return or just after return in the calling function.  Note the calling function is initializing 8 of these, and I show them all, with all them filled with either garbage or inaccessible memory.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**, disassembly of function in question:

```
Breakpoint 1, ALIKEC_res_strings_init () at alike.c:75
75    return res;
(gdb) p res.current[0]
$1 = 0x7ffff46a0aa5 "%s%s%s%s"
(gdb) p res.current[1]
$2 = 0x1400000001 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1400000001>
(gdb) disas /m ALIKEC_res_strings_init
Dump of assembler code for function ALIKEC_res_strings_init:
53  struct ALIKEC_res_strings ALIKEC_res_strings_init() {
   0x00007ffff4687fc0 <+0>: endbr64 

54    struct ALIKEC_res_strings res;

55  
56    res.target = (const char **) R_alloc(5, sizeof(const char *));
   0x00007ffff4687fc4 <+4>: push   %r12
   0x00007ffff4687fc6 <+6>: mov    $0x8,%esi
   0x00007ffff4687fcb <+11>:    mov    %rdi,%r12
   0x00007ffff4687fce <+14>:    push   %rbx
   0x00007ffff4687fcf <+15>:    mov    $0x5,%edi
   0x00007ffff4687fd4 <+20>:    sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00007ffff4687fd8 <+24>:    callq  0x7ffff4687180 <R_alloc@plt>
   0x00007ffff4687fdd <+29>:    mov    $0x8,%esi
   0x00007ffff4687fe2 <+34>:    mov    $0x5,%edi
   0x00007ffff4687fe7 <+39>:    mov    %rax,%rbx

57    res.current = (const char **) R_alloc(5, sizeof(const char *));
   0x00007ffff4687fea <+42>:    callq  0x7ffff4687180 <R_alloc@plt>

58  
59    res.target[0] = "%s%s%s%s";
   0x00007ffff4687fef <+47>:    lea    0x1764a(%rip),%rdx        # 0x7ffff469f640
   0x00007ffff4687ff6 <+54>:    lea    0x18aa8(%rip),%rcx        # 0x7ffff46a0aa5
   0x00007ffff4687ffd <+61>:    mov    %rcx,(%rbx)

60    res.target[1] = "";

61    res.target[2] = "";
   0x00007ffff4688000 <+64>:    mov    %rdx,0x10(%rbx)

62    res.target[3] = "";
   0x00007ffff4688004 <+68>:    mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbx)

63    res.target[4] = "";
   0x00007ffff4688008 <+72>:    mov    %rdx,0x20(%rbx)

64  
65    res.tar_pre = "be";

66  
67    res.current[0] = "%s%s%s%s";
   0x00007ffff468800c <+76>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%r12)
   0x00007ffff4688011 <+81>:    mov    %rcx,(%rax)

68    res.current[1] = "";

69    res.current[2] = "";
   0x00007ffff4688014 <+84>:    mov    %rdx,0x10(%rax)

70    res.current[3] = "";
   0x00007ffff4688018 <+88>:    mov    %rdx,0x18(%rax)

71    res.current[4] = "";
   0x00007ffff468801c <+92>:    mov    %rdx,0x20(%rax)

72  
73    res.cur_pre = "is";

74  
75    return res;
=> 0x00007ffff4688020 <+96>:    lea    0x14fe0(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffff469d007
   0x00007ffff4688027 <+103>:   mov    %rax,0x10(%r12)
   0x00007ffff468802c <+108>:   lea    0x14fcd(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffff469d000
   0x00007ffff4688033 <+115>:   mov    %rbx,(%r12)
   0x00007ffff4688037 <+119>:   mov    %rax,0x18(%r12)
   0x00007ffff468803c <+124>:   add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00007ffff4688040 <+128>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00007ffff4688041 <+129>:   mov    %r12,%rax
   0x00007ffff4688044 <+132>:   pop    %r12
   0x00007ffff4688046 <+134>:   retq   
   0x00007ffff4688047:  nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

End of assembler dump.
```

**UPDATE 4**:

So, trying to parse through the standard here are the parts of it that seem relevant ([C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> 6.3.2.3 Par7 Conversions > Other Operands > Pointers
>
> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type.  **If the resulting  pointer  is  not  correctly 
>   aligned** 68) for  the  referenced  type,  the  behavior  is undefined.
>   Otherwise, when  converted  back  again,  the  result  shall  compare 
>   equal to the original pointer.  When a pointer to an object is
>   converted to a pointer to a character type,the result points to the
>   lowest addressed byte of the object.  Successive increments of
>   the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the
>   remaining bytes of the object.

6.5 Par6 Expressions

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the
>   declared type of the object,  if  any. 87)  If  a  value  is  stored  into
>   an  object  having  no  declared  type  through  an lvalue having a
>   type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes
>   the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent
>   accesses that do not modify the  stored  value.   If  a  value  is 
>   copied  into  an  object  having  no  declared  type 
>   using memcpy or memmove, or is copied as an array of character type, then
>   the effective type of the modified object for that access and for
>   subsequent accesses that do not modify the value is the effective type
>   of the object from which the value is copied, if it has one.  **For all
>   other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective
>   type of the object is simply the type of the lvalue used for the
>   access.**
>
> 87)   Allocated objects have no declared type.

IIUC `R_alloc` returns an offset into a `malloc`ed block that is guaranteed to be `double` aligned, and the size of the block after the offset is of the requested size (there is also allocation before the offset for R specific data).  `R_alloc` casts that pointer to `(char *)` on return.

> Section 6.2.5 Par 29
>
> A pointer  to void shall  have  the  same  representation  and 
>   alignment  requirements  as  a pointer  to  a  character 
>   type. 48) Similarly, pointers  to  qualified  or  unqualified  versions 
>   of compatible  types  shall  have  the  same  representation  and 
>   alignment  requirements.   All pointers to structure types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements as  each  other.
>   All  pointers  to  union  types  shall  have  the  same 
>   representation  and alignment  requirements  as  each  other.
>   Pointers  to  other  types  need  not  have  the  same representation
>   or alignment requirements.
>
> 48)   The  same  representation  and  alignment  requirements  are meant  to  imply  interchangeability  asarguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.

So the question is "are we allowed to recast the `(char *)` to `(const char **)` and write to it as `(const char **)`".  My reading of the above is that so long as pointers on the systems the code run in have alignment compatible with `double` alignment, then its okay.

Are we violating "strict aliasing"? i.e.:

> 6.5 Par 7
>
> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types: 88)
>
> —  a type compatible with the effective type of the object
>   ...
>
> 88) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

So, what should the compiler think the **effective type** of the object pointed to by `res.target` (or `res.current`) is?  Presumably the declared type `(const char **)`, or is this actually ambiguous?  It feels to me that it isn't in this case only because there is no other 'lvalue' in scope that accesses the same object.

I'll admit I'm struggling mightily to extract sense from these sections of the standard.

Comment: If not already examined it may be worth looking at the disassembly to see exactly what is being done. And also to compare the disassembly between gcc versions.

Comment: I wouldn't try to mess with the trunk version of GCC. It's nice to have fun with, but it's called trunk for a reason. Unfortunately it's almost impossible to tell what's wrong without (1) having your code and exact config (2) having the same GCC version (3) on the same architecture. I'd suggest checking if this persist when 10.0.1 moves from trunk to stable.

Comment: Using gdb on optimized code is often misleading, since the compiler will often rearrange or combine code in such a way that it doesn't really match up with source lines in a one-to-one fashion.  I agree with kaylum that if you really think gcc might be failing to initialize your variable when it should, you'll have to read the assembly to confirm it.  But it's always far more likely that the compiler is just fine and your code has a bug, maybe a subtle one.

Comment: It looks like the suspected function is pretty short.  If you pull it out into its own file, together with the definitions of the relevant structs, and a harness function to call it, that would be a pretty good test case, and nice to try in http://godbolt.org.  It could also be helpful if you could disassemble the .o file that the original source file compiled into (`objdump --disassemble`) and post that somewhere for inspection.

Comment: The other thing I would try in `gdb` is to inspect the contents of `res` just before the function returns, and in the calling function after the return, to try to be certain whether the initialization happened or not.  If it really didn't, then it could be a compiler bug.  If it did, then you have to figure out why it changed later, and gdb's watchpoint feature is a good way to do that.

Comment: One more comment: `-mtune=native` optimizes for the particular CPU that your machine has.  That will be different for different testers and may be part of the issue.  If you run the compilation with `-v` you should be able to see which cpu family that is on your machine (e.g. `-mtune=skylake` on my computer).

Comment: @NateEldredge does the additional info make you lean on way or another on whether the array was initialized properly?  It really looks like it hasn't been.

Comment: Still hard to tell from debug runs.  The disassembly should be conclusive.  You don't need to extract anything, just find the .o file produced when you compiled the project and disassemble it.  You could also use the `disassemble` instruction inside gdb.

Comment: That disassembly shows that the compiled code is indeed wrong.  So now you can either try to create a testcase to submit as a gcc bug report (precise compiler options will be important, including as I mentioned something other than `-mtune=native` which is ambiguous), or just wait a while and see if they fix it.  In the meantime you probably want to hold off using this version of the compiler to build your project.

Comment: Anyway, congratulations, you're one of the rare few whose problem actually was a compiler bug.

Comment: `what should the compiler think the effective type of the object pointed to by res.target (or res.current) is?` The effective type is generally the last type you stored inside the memory. So for example `alignas(long) char arr[20];` - `arr` has no effective type. After ex. `*(long*)arr = 20;` the effective type becomes `long`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: So in this case, we don't know the effective type of the object pointed to by the pointer returned by `R_alloc()`, because we don't know what `R_alloc()` actually did.  The compiler doesn't know either.  But if I understand you correctly, it shouldn't matter, because we don't actually access that object - we merely overwrite it, thus giving it a new effective type (`const char *`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Summary:** This appears to be a bug in gcc, related to string optimization.  A self-contained testcase is below.  There was initially some doubt as to whether the code is correct, but I think it is.

I have reported the bug as [PR 93982](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93982).  [A proposed fix was committed](https://gcc.gnu.org/g:f26688fbe441375e907f0dd2f35837681870b1f4) but it does not fix it in all cases, leading to the followup [PR 94015](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94015) ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/dLw4jg)).

You should be able to work around the bug by compiling with the flag `-fno-optimize-strlen`.

---

I was able to reduce your test case to the following minimal example (also on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AEnGyd)):

```
struct a {
    const char ** target;
};

char* R_alloc(void);

struct a foo(void) {
    struct a res;
    res.target = (const char **) R_alloc();
    res.target[0] = "12345678";
    res.target[1] = "";
    res.target[2] = "";
    res.target[3] = "";
    res.target[4] = "";
    return res;
}
```

With gcc trunk (gcc version 10.0.1 20200225 (experimental)) and `-O2` (all other options turned out to be unnecessary), the generated assembly on amd64 is as follows:

```
.LC0:
        .string "12345678"
.LC1:
        .string ""
foo:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    R_alloc
        movq    $.LC0, (%rax)
        movq    $.LC1, 16(%rax)
        movq    $.LC1, 24(%rax)
        movq    $.LC1, 32(%rax)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

So you are quite right that the compiler is failing to initialize `res.target[1]` (note the conspicuous absence of `movq $.LC1, 8(%rax)`).

It is interesting to play with the code and see what affects the "bug".  Perhaps significantly, changing the return type of `R_alloc` to `void *` makes it go away, and gives you "correct" assembly output.  Maybe less significantly but more amusingly, changing the string `"12345678"` to be either longer or shorter also makes it go away.

---

**Previous discussion, now resolved - the code is apparently legal.**

The question I have is whether your code is actually legal.  The fact that you take the `char *` returned by `R_alloc()` and cast it to `const char **`, and then store a `const char *` seems like it might violate the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1), as `char` and `const char *` are not compatible types.  There is an exception that allows you to access any object as `char` (to implement things like `memcpy`), but this is the other way around, and as best I understand it, that's not allowed.  It makes your code produce undefined behavior and so the compiler can legally do whatever the heck it wants.

If this is so, the correct fix would be for R to change their code so that `R_alloc()` returns `void *` instead of `char *`.  Then there would be no aliasing problem.  Unfortunately, that code is outside your control, and it's not clear to me how you can use this function at all without violating strict aliasing.  A workaround might be to interpose a temporary variable, e.g. `void *tmp = R_alloc(); res.target = tmp;` which solves the problem in the test case, but I'm still not sure if it's legal.

However, I am not sure of this "strict aliasing" hypothesis, because compiling with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, which AFAIK is supposed to make gcc allow such constructs, does **not** make the problem go away!

---

**Update.** Trying some different options, I found that either `-fno-optimize-strlen` or `-fno-tree-forwprop` will result in "correct" code being generated.  Also, using `-O1 -foptimize-strlen` yields the incorrect code (but `-O1 -ftree-forwprop` does not).

After a little `git bisect` exercise, the error seems to have been introduced in [commit 34fcf41e30ff56155e996f5e04](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=34fcf41e30ff56155e996f5e04).

---

**Update 2.** I tried digging into the gcc source a little bit, just to see what I could learn.  (I don't claim to be any sort of compiler expert!)

It looks like the code in `tree-ssa-strlen.c` is meant to keep track of strings appearing in the program.  As near as I can tell, the bug is that in looking at the statement `res.target[0] = "12345678";` the compiler conflates the *address* of the string literal `"12345678"` with the string itself.  (That seems to be related to [this suspicious code](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/tree-ssa-strlen.c;h=9a88a85b07c056a37a18ee12a8201c5659bc8037;hb=HEAD#l4694) which was added in the aforementioned commit, where if it tries to count the bytes of a "string" that is actually an address, it instead looks at what that address points to.)

So it thinks that the statement `res.target[0] = "12345678"`, instead of storing the *address* of `"12345678"` at the address `res.target`, is storing the string itself at that address, as if the statement were `strcpy(res.target, "12345678")`.  Note for what's ahead that this would result in the trailing nul being stored at address `res.target+8` (at this stage in the compiler, all offsets are in bytes).

Now when the compiler looks at `res.target[1] = ""`, it likewise treats this as if it were `strcpy(res.target+8, "")`, the 8 coming from the size of a `char *`.  That is, as if it were simply storing a nul byte at address `res.target+8`.  However, the compiler "knows" that the previous statement already stored a nul byte at that very address! As such, this statement is "redundant" and can be discarded ([here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/tree-ssa-strlen.c;h=9a88a85b07c056a37a18ee12a8201c5659bc8037;hb=HEAD#l5017)).

This explains why the string has to be exactly 8 characters long to trigger the bug.  (Though other multiples of 8 can also trigger the bug in other situations.)

Comment: FWIW recasting to a different type of pointer is [documented](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Transient-storage-allocation).   I don't know about aliasing to know whether it is ok to recast to `int*` but not to `const char**`.

Comment: If my understanding of strict aliasing is correct, then the cast to `int *` is also illegal (or rather, actually storing `int`s there is illegal).

Comment: This has nothing to do with strict aliasing rule. Strict aliasing rule is about _accessing_ the data that you already _stored_ using different handle. As you only assign here, it doesn't touch strict aliasing rule. Casting pointers is valid when both pointer types have same alignment requirements, but here you are casting from `char*` and working on x86_64... I see no UB here, this is gcc bug.

Comment: Yes and no, @KamilCuk.  In the standard's terminology, "accessing" includes both reading and modifying the value of an object.  The strict aliasing rule therefore does speak to "storing".  It is not limited to read-back operations. But for objects with no declared type, that is mooted by the fact that writing to such an object automatically *changes* its effective type to correspond to what was written. The objects without a declared type are exactly the dynamically allocated ones (regardless of the type of the pointer by which they are accessed), so indeed there is no SA violation here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Hmm.  But we don't know where the pointer returned by `R_alloc()` comes from, or at least, the compiler doesn't know.  It isn't necessarily memory allocated by `malloc()`.  Is the compiler obligated to do the right thing here, merely because it *might* be dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: Excellent effort and discussion. UV worthy. Sorry I can't help, have no R to test with and last check it wanted about a huge number of dependencies to install.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Note that the test case in my answer doesn't need R or anything else.   You don't need a definition of the `R_alloc()` function, you can see the bug just by inspecting the generated assembly.  (You can supply your own definition of this function, preferably in another source file so the compiler can't see it, if you want an example you can link and execute.  I have such an example if you want it.)

Comment: @NateEldredge, supposing that the compiler claims to be conforming, then "I don't know whether the object being accessed has a declared type" (if that's even the case here) is not an excuse for failing to conform.  So in that sense, yes, it must do the right thing. But also, in practice, here, as in many areas, the undefinedness of the behavior of non-conforming code is first and foremost license for the compiler to do a *natural* thing, even if that may be incorrect on some level or may produce different results on different machines if the code does not conform.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: So for instance, if I define `R_alloc()` in another translation unit as `char* R_alloc(void) { return malloc(5*sizeof(const char *)); }`, then it sounds like the program would be strictly legal, and the code generated by gcc would still be wrong.

Comment: Yes, @Nate, with that definition of `R_alloc()`, the program is conforming, regardless of in which translation unit `R_alloc()` is defined.  It is the compiler that fails to conform here.

Comment: @BrodieG I believe someone has earned a decent sized bounty here